# What is the defacto bytes type in rust?

Tags: rust

What is the defacto "bytes" type in rust? Say I have serialized some object what would be the expected type

In python there's `bytes` and in golang there's `[]byte`. What is rust's equivalent?

Seems really simple but I guess I'm expressing this concept wrong, as I haven't found anything in searches

Comment: Are you looking for an array or `Vec` of `u8` values, or are there operations you're looking for on a byte sequence that you'd want a byte-specific type to support?

Comment: `Vec<u8>` maybe what I'm after, looking to do some simple send/receive of data over a network connection

Comment: A byte in rust is by definition an `u8`

Comment: Also take a look at the [bytes crate](https://crates.io/crates/bytes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Often the best place to start is related Rust documentation. You mention reading data from a network connection, so let's look at [`TcpStream`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html). It implements the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait's [`read` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read), which has the type

> ```
> fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>
> ```

which should make it relatively clear what you might expect. `&mut [u8]` is a mutable reference for a Rust [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) where the underlying data is of type [`u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html). Where specifically that `u8` slice comes from is up to you as the caller. It could be from an [array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) or [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) depending on your requirements for dynamic sizing, or any other type that supports it.